# How to get local bzr commits to server?

Tags: bazaar

[lanchpad.net](http://launchpad.net/) states that for project [Emle - Electronic Mathematics Laboratory Equipment](https://launchpad.net/emle), the current focus of development is the [2.0 series](https://launchpad.net/emle/2.0)

This is what I have done so far:

1. Set the launchpad.net project to import from the [sourceforge.net](http://sourceforge.net/) project [Emle](http://sourceforge.net/projects/emle) (this actually set the launchpad.net project to mirror the sourceforge.net project rather than just inport the content once)
2. Examined the launchpad.net project to see that the three commits (#1 - #3) which were done in the sourceorge.net project previousley made it into launchpad.net.
3. Used  [bzr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bazaar_(software)) to get the launchpad.net project which I did while it was still set for mirroring.
4. Made three changes and commits using bzr (#4 - #6).
5. Was unable to see the changes on the launchpad.net site.
6. Requested the mirroring to be stopped (it did).

Here is an extract from lanchpad.net for project Emle [2.0 series](https://launchpad.net/emle/2.0) showing that launchpad.net has #1 - #3:

```
Code for this series
The following branch has been registered as the mainline branch for this release series:

lp:emle - C.W.Holeman II
3 revisions, 3 in the past month.
```

This shows that #4 - #6 have some kind of problem:

```
$ bzr  missing 
Using saved parent location: bzr+ssh://bazaar.launchpad.net/~cwhii/emle/2.0/
You have 3 extra revision(s):
------------------------------------------------------------
revno: 6
committer: C.W.Holeman II <cwhii_hcnual@julianlocals.com>
branch nick: lp.emle
timestamp: Sat 2010-02-27 09:13:29 -0800
message:
  #528096 Corrected setting of paramter value for emleDir to the dir
  attribute value of the message element in the lanuage message file,
  lang/emle_lang_XX.xml. Minor refactor -  Consistently setting the dir and lang
  attributes of html, head and body elements.
------------------------------------------------------------
revno: 5
committer: C.W.Holeman II <cwhii_hcnual@julianlocals.com>
branch nick: lp.emle
timestamp: Sat 2010-02-27 09:08:09 -0800
message:
  Minor refactor - improved comment regarding workaround for replacing
  html vs head and body elements from index html with lab transformed
  XML (to html) document tree.  
------------------------------------------------------------
revno: 4
committer: C.W.Holeman II <cwhii_hcnual@julianlocals.com>
branch nick: lp.emle
timestamp: Sat 2010-02-27 09:04:29 -0800
message:
  #529089 #529087 Index file html tag lang attribute corrected and empty link tag changed
```

How do I get the changes that are in bzr on my system to apply to launchpad.net?

More info:

```
$ bzr check
Checking working tree at '/home/cwhii/work/lp.emle'.
Checking branch at 'file:///home/cwhii/work/lp.emle/'.
Checking repository at 'file:///home/cwhii/work/lp.emle/'.
checked repository <bzrlib.transport.local.LocalTransport url=file:///home/cwhii/work/lp.emle/> format <RepositoryFormat2a> 
     6 revisions
    83 file-ids
checked branch file:///home/cwhii/work/lp.emle/ format Branch format 7

$ bzr merge
Merging from remembered parent location bzr+ssh://bazaar.launchpad.net/~cwhii/emle/2.0/
Nothing to do.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turnes out that lp:~cwhii/emle/2.0 is an auto-import branch from svn.  You're not allowed to write to import branches, even if you own them, because that would cause confusion when the auto-import robot tries to keep writing to them.

So what I suggest you do here is

1- go to http://launchpad.net/people/+newteam and make an *emle-dev* team, so that you can later let other people write to this project if you want

2- go to http://code.launchpad.net/~cwhii/emle/2.0/+edit and change the *name* field to "2.0-import" to "get it out of the way"

3- on your pc, in the branch directory, type "bzr push --remember lp:~emle-dev/emle/2.0"

4- on http://launchpad.net/emle/2.0/+linkbranch enter *~emle-dev/emle/2.0* to indicate this is now the focus of development

hope that helps.

(sorry they're not real links, I don't have enough karma here.)

The poor message here is https://launchpad.net/bugs/543797/